# HTML Select input option drop down arrow not showing on chrome

Tags: html, select, input, caret

I included a form in a modal. The form contain a select input. The problem I'm having is that the select drop down arrow shows on other browsers except chrome. So I want to add a caret icon. What is the best way to do this? Alternative solution is also welcomed

Answer (score 2):

First at all you need to remove appearance for select in your css:

```
select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

You can add your own image arrow with something like this:

```
select {
background: #fff url(myimagepath/image.png) no-repeat 0 90%;
}
```

Or if you don't want to use images you can do something like this:

```
select:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 6px solid #f99300;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```